Prevent Flutter Background image from resizing when keyboard toggled on pushed screen in CupertinoTabScaffold
I know that this question popped up many times regarding the general app scaffold:

Flutter: Background image is squeezing when keyboard appears (suggesting to set the resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false on the concerned Scaffold, which I want to avoid for better UX).
How can I avoid the background image to shrink when my keyboard is active?, https://www.flutterbeads.com/set-background-image-in-flutter/ (suggesting to put the container out of the scaffold, which is the solution I've selected).

The second suggestion gives the following code for a fixed background image (not moving with incoming keyboard) applied to all possible CupertinoTabViews() returned via the tabBuilder of a CupertinoTabScaffold:
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/bg.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
          /// Please do not suggest to change this to false, not an option for me
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          /// The Tabs are irrelevant for this code sample
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(...),
          tabBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                /// transparent to make bg image visible
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                  middle: Text('hello'),
                ),
                child: MyFirstPage(),
              );
            });
          },
        ),
      );

This works. E.g., if you have a text field within the MyFirstPage() widget, the keyboard slides in and the background image does not move. BUT, my problem is: Let's say there's a button in your MyFirstPage() widget. If that button is hit, you call Navigator.of(context).push() in your code to push a widget (let's call that one MyWidgetAboveFirstPage()) above your MyFirstPage(). You want to apply the same background image to MyWidgetAboveFirstPage(), so its build() method returns sth like:
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/bg.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text("Content of the Page Above"),
      );

If MyWidgetAboveFirstPage() contains a text field (or any other widget that may trigger a keyboard); as soon as your software keyboard is triggered on that page, you're actually back to the same problem: The background image resizes. Supposingly because with your MyWidgetAboveFirstPage(), you're only applying the background image within the boundaries of the CupertinoTabView(), which goes back to the same result as if you would apply the outermost container inside instead of outside of your CupertinoTabScaffold().
The only way to fight this problem I've currently found (that is, to also apply a fixed background on screens pushed on top of your base screen with Navigator.of(context).push() when using a CupertinoTabScaffold() is to push that screen via Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true), as this will apply the background image to the entire screen again (outside from the CupertinoTabView() boundaries).
But this also eliminates the iOS-navigation, which leaves the bottom navigation bar active / visible by default when doing Navigator.of(context).push. Is it actually possibly to apply the background image to the entire screen surface of a CupertinoTabScaffold, even for pushed screens, but below the navigation bar? Otherwise I suppose what I'm trying to do is technically impossible ?
SAMPLE APP
Feel free to play around with a sample app I've prepared which exactly illustrates the issue. Just add any background image at assets/imgs/bg.png, update your pubspec.yml and run the application, and you'll see what I mean:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// to be able to use TextFormField within Cupertino
    return ContainerWithBG(
      child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.abc,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.adb,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
        tabBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                  middle: Text(
                      'Base Tab $index - Img not moving when keyboard toggled'),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Random Content of Tab $index',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      const InputField(),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const UpperLayer(
                                triggeredViaRootNav: false,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Push To Upper Screen (Normal Push)',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const UpperLayer(
                                triggeredViaRootNav: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Push To Upper Screen (Rootnav Push)',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Text Field
class InputField extends StatelessWidget {
  const InputField({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Material() wrapper to be able to use TextFormField() within Cupertino
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// BG IMG Decoration
class ContainerWithBG extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ContainerWithBG({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/bg.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class UpperLayer extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Just for app bar naming for better understanding
  final bool triggeredViaRootNav;

  const UpperLayer({
    super.key,
    required this.triggeredViaRootNav,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ContainerWithBG(
      child: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text(
            (triggeredViaRootNav
                ? 'Pushed Screen - Img NOT Moving when keyboard toggled (RootNav Push)'
                : 'Pushed Screen - Img Moving when keyboard toggled (Normal Push)'),
          ),
        ),
        child: const Center(
          child: InputField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

